# Do bluetooth syli work with any touchscreen?

Tags: tablet, displays, touchscreen, graphics-tablet

I have a hanspree HT225HPB touchscreen monitor hooked up to my PC and I'm looking to start using it for digital art. As I understand it, it's not pressure-sensitive on its own, but is it possible to purchase a pressure-sensitive stylus that connects to my PC, or something similar?

I have seen a number of Bluetooth styli and ones advertised as being 'universal', but it's not clear whether these work with any touchscreen, or only touchscreens that were designed to work with a stylus from the start.

As an alternate way to ask this question: I own a hanspree HT225HPB, can I purchase a stylus that will give me pressure sensitivity with this display?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Irsu85 I can try to add some more detail but I'm struggling to think of a better way to ask the question. What I want to know is: if I purchase a stylus that is pressure and tilt sensitive, will this work with my existing touchscreen monitor? Or do they all rely on hardware within the screen to work?

Comment: I can't give an answer, but the question is now more clear for me to read. Thanks